# SQL weird result after request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a problem with mySQL queries and strange results.
For example:

Before query:
*money for id 48 is 7.54*

Query:
*UPDATE account SET money = money - 7.54 WHERE id = 48*

After this query;
*money for id 48 is -0.000000038147*

Why I can’t get just 0? What can I do to repair it?

Comment: What is the data type of column *money*

Comment: I guess `money` is a float, which is an approximate datatype. A `decimal` would work better

Comment: I use varchar and never had such issues;)

Comment: Sounds like a case of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken to me